Can I split a 220 on an old house if I add a neutral wire?
I'm working on my late brothers house and need a 110 for the sump pump and one for the furnace. The house was built/wired in 1922. It has a 220 that was used for heating/AC, but it is a 3 wire circuit. I'd rather not put the furnace and sump pump on the same breaker. Access to the breaker box is very limited. If I can get a single wire run from it, can I split the dual breaker into 2 by replacing it and split the 220 into two 110 using the new single wire as an insulated neutral?
And there are no ground wires run for this house

All 240 breakers have 120v on each side.  You cannot add a single neutral wire if using cables.  If panel space is limited, you can add a sub panel close by and free up space.  You said no ground wires, so are the three wires hot, hot, neutral(unsafe) or hot, hot, ground?

You are presuming that neutral is the missing wire from the 3-wire supply.  Most likely on a pre-1954 circuit, the missing wire is ground and neutral is already present.  On an electric service from the utility, the utility does NOT deliver ground, and you are required to establish ground locally.

This would never meet code. What you're describing is conceptually an attempt at a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC) but running a single neutral wire is not the way to do this. By code, all conductors involved in a circuit must run together, either in a cable sleeve ("romex") or in conduit. You also need handle-tied breakers for a MWBC, so even though there are 2 breakers on opposite phases, they turn on and off as one - this is to prevent the circuit from being half-energized and dangerous.
Your best bet is to do a full rewire of two circuits all the way back to the panel.
